# Boost read_some function throws eof exception

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

My server is constantly waiting for the client to send it 3 bytes, that indicates what the client does next. After the operation the client requested is done, the server waits again for 3 bytes from the client.

I'm using this code for receiving 3 bytes from a client.

```
char buf[3];
boost::system::error_code error;
size_t length = 0;

//Read 3 bytes from client
while( length < 3 )
{
    length += socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&buf[length], 3 - length), error);

    if (error)
    {
        cout << length << endl; //prints 0
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    }
}
```

However, while waiting "read_some" function suddenly throws EOF error.

 I've read that EOF means that the client socket has been close. I've checked and the client socket is never closed.

I have no idea what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated

Edit: If I ignore the error, the server works fine. But I'm sure this is not the right way to deal with this situation.

Comment: Can you post the client's code? Maybe socket goes out of scope in it?

Comment: The client connects to the server, sends it 3 bytes(which the server receive and does what it should) and then runs in an infinite loop doing something that is not related to the server. Client is fine. Again, the socket is never closed.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [Streams, Short Reads and Short Writes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html#boost_asio.overview.core.streams.why_eof_is_an_error) states:

> #### Why EOF is an Error
>
> The end of a stream can cause read, `async_read`, `read_until` or `async_read_until` functions to violate their contract. E.g. a read of N bytes may finish early due to EOF. 
>   An EOF error may be used to distinguish the end of a stream from a successful read of size 0.